# ms access GROUP BY error

Tags: sql-server, group-by, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to run this SQL in MS access

```
SELECT `orig`.`SONG TITLE`,`orig`.`PUBLISHER`,`orig`.`CFG DESCRIPTION`
FROM `Sheet1` AS `orig`
INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS `Sale`
ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
GROUP BY orig.`SONG TITLE` , orig.`PUBLISHER`
;
```

I get an error saying: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'CFG DESCRIPTION' as a part of an aggregate function"

When I run this query without the GROUP BY clause all works fine. What am I doing wrong with the GROUP BY??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group by` clause means that you get one result row per distinct combination of the grouped columns. This means your select list can only contains columns that are grouped by, or aggregate functions (e.g., `count`, `sum`, `min`, `max`, etc.)

So you should either add `CFG DESCRIPTION` to the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT `orig`.`SONG TITLE`,`orig`.`PUBLISHER`,`orig`.`CFG DESCRIPTION`
FROM `Sheet1` AS `orig`
INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS `Sale`
ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
GROUP BY orig.`SONG TITLE` , orig.`PUBLISHER`,`orig`.`CFG DESCRIPTION`
;
```

Or remove it from the select list:

```
SELECT `orig`.`SONG TITLE`,`orig`.`PUBLISHER`
FROM `Sheet1` AS `orig`
INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS `Sale`
ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
GROUP BY orig.`SONG TITLE` , orig.`PUBLISHER`
;
```

Depending on the result you need, of course.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is an all-or-nothing concept, where every column you select needs to be in the clause unless it's an aggregate.  Include `orig`.`CFG DESCRIPTION` at the end of the GROUP BY and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add orig.[GFC DESCRIPTION] to your Group By:

GROUP BY orig.[SONG TITLE] , orig.[PUBLISHER], orig.[GFC DESCRIPTION]

If that does not work for your situation, place the orig.[GFC DESCRIPTION] in an aggregate function:

SELECT `orig`.`SONG TITLE`,`orig`.`PUBLISHER`,MIN(`orig`.`CFG DESCRIPTION`)
FROM `Sheet1` AS `orig`
INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS `Sale`
ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
GROUP BY orig.`SONG TITLE` , orig.`PUBLISHER`
;

You can use any aggregate function, such as MAX, FIRST (Access Specific), etc.